# How do I print several timestamps from a transcript?

Tags: regex, python-3.7

I am trying to print all existing timestamps from a transcript (.txt file).

A short extract from the transcript:

```
36
00:01:36,990 --> 00:01:39,119
Text...

37
00:01:39,119 --> 00:01:41,759
Text...

38
00:01:41,759 --> 00:01:43,799
Text...
```

My code looks like this so far:

```
import re
timestamps = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s-->\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}")
for line in transcript:
    linenum += 1
    if pattern.search(line) != None:
        timestamps.append(linenum, line.rstrip('\n'))
print(timestamps)
```

The output is... nothing. No error or anything else. But I wish to print out all lines that contain timestamps.

I don't know what's wrong with the code or how to fix that. Can anyone please help? It'd be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Some lines contained in transcript will be usefull.

Comment: Maybe there are no matching strings in the `transcript`? Show its contents. Also, you need `timestamps.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))` or `timestamps.append([linenum, line.rstrip('\n')])`. See https://ideone.com/vFt1Xm

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thank you very much for the tip! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append either tuples or lists to the `timestamps` list.

```
import re
timestamps = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile(r"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s-->\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}")
for line in transcript:
    linenum += 1
    if pattern.search(line):
        timestamps.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
print(timestamps)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vFt1Xm).

With the input like

```
12:12:12,234 --> 12:13:46,346
Blah
12:14:12,121 --> 12:15:89,678
Blah2
```

The output is

```
[(1, '12:12:12,234 --> 12:13:46,346'), (3, '12:14:12,121 --> 12:15:89,678')]
```